# Query didn't update the rows which contains a specific values

Tags: sql

I want to update column called `target_ops_num` on case `if` column `technology` is `UMTS` then get value from `[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier]` ELSE column `technology` is `GSM` then get the value from `[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_gsm_carrier]` based on column `[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[n_cell_name]`

as this is the query I created as the below one:

```
UPDATE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
SET [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_ops_num] = (CASE WHEN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[technology] = 'UMTS' 
THEN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier].[opsnum_umts] ELSE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_gsm_carrier].[opsnum_gsm] END)
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier]
ON [n_cell_name] = [cell_name_umts]
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_gsm_carrier]
ON [n_cell_name] = [cell_name]
```

So the problem was the query takes about 18 min and didn't update the rows which contains column `technology` value `GSM` it updates the rows with column `technology` value `UMTS` only

any one have a suugestion about this query?

Comment: @BilboBaggins  could you see the update Bilbo Baggins lease the problem was the query update only the row which was column `technology` = `UMTS` only

Comment: Are those 2 the only possible values in the technology column?

Comment: @BilboBaggins yes those are the only 2 values in the `technology` there's are no more options

Comment: Try running a select with those joins so you can see all the columns side by side. Does anything look off?